# Replace link to DispForm.aspx with call to javascript function in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, listitem

I made a Calendar View in SharePoint to show all the projects each functional team has to work on for the month.  What I would like to do is replace the link to dispform.aspx with a script to hide any item that doesn't share a project name with the item clicked on.

Example:
Project 1 runs from August 1-August 15
Project 1 runs from August 20-August 25
Project 2 runs from August 15-August 26

When the user clicks on either of the Project 1 list items, I want to run my script to hide Project 2.

The issue is that I can't find a way to stop the call to the DispForm.aspx page when the item is clicked on.

EDIT: Answered my own post: Found this link to disable the links + add javascript to the OnClick event

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/498b171a-b00a-4dd9-8bee-2348bc4ccbd8/

Comment: you can answer your own post. Just answer this regularly instead of in your post itself - after 72 hours I think you can then accept your own answer.